# Cauchy-Lipschitz on closed sets

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:I \times U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ($I$ interval of $\mathbb{R}$, $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$) and consider the ODE
$$\begin{array}{l} y'(t)=f(t,y(t)), \quad t \in I, \qquad
y(0)=y_0 \end{array},$$
where $y^0 \in U$.

In general the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem is stated for open sets $U$.
My question is how to deal with closed $U$ ?
For instance, assume that
$$f \in C^1([0,+\infty)\times[0,1]), \qquad f<0, \qquad y^0 \in [0,1].$$
How to use the "standard" version of the theorem to directly deduce that there exists a maximal solution $J=(\alpha,\beta) \subset [0,+\infty)$ and $y \in C^1([\alpha,\beta])$ such that $y(\alpha)=1$ and $y(\beta)=0$ ?

Comment: Assuming that the one-sided derivatives exist in $y=0$ and $1$ and are continuous in $t$, continue the function with $f(t,0)+\partial_yf(t,0)y$ for $y<0$ and $f(t,1)+\partial_yf(t,1)(y-1)$ for $y>1$ and apply the theorem to some open neighborhood of the closed set.

Comment: Ok, and the rest of the conclusion follows from the finite time blow up theorem, correct ?

So for "closed versions" of C-L we always proceed by extension, there are other tricks ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. If one could get $f\le c<0$ on a large enough set, then you reach $y=0$ in finite time. But take something like $y'=f(t,y)=-y-e^{-2t}$, then $y(t)=(1+y_0)e^{-t}-e^{-2t}=y_0e^{-t}+e^{-t}(1-e^{-t})$ never reaches $y=0$ for $y_0>0$.

Comment: It's $f(t,y)=-y+e^{-2t}$, no ? Anyway you are right, we need such a bound. I forgot that the time interval was unbounded. This makes me think that we shall also need that $\partial_y f(t,1)$ is bounded for your extension to stay negative close enough to $y=1^+$, no ?